# How to create a message set for CWF to do opaque parsing?

Tags: messagebroker

I will receive messages with 5 different formats. All the messages will have first 20 characters in the same format. I have to find out the message type using characters 10 to 20. Then apply the appropriate message set. I dont want a compute node to figure out the text rather I want to create a message format that will parse 0 to 20 and 5 other message formats to parse the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Using Websphere Message Broker v7, I created a message set by defining the header fields and since the body will be of varying length, I defined the body as complex type with Composition as "message". After I figure out the message type from the header, i applied the appropriate message set to parse the message.